# Access method in class library

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've moved a class in my project into a class Library in the same solution.   I've added a reference in the web project to the class library.

How do I access the methods in the class library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the method and class are public and instantiate to use it:

```
YourClass yourClass = new YourClass();
yourClass.YourMethod();
```

Or, if your method is static:

```
YourClass.YourMethod();
```

Make sure to include the namespace of your class is your target classes using statements, i.e.

```
using ClassLibrary;
```

If you're unsure of the namespace of `YourClass` you can find it within the Class file at the top, directly beneath your using statements. Or you can mouse over the `YourClass` text in the Visual Studios Editor and then select the namespace by clicking the button that appears.

Comment: May want to do a sanity check by explicitly calling the namespace: LibraryName.YourClass newYourClass = new LibraryName.YourClass();

Comment: Perhaps. But I wouldn't encourage writing namespaces within classes unless there's ambiguity between two classes.

Comment: I keep getting "The type or namspace could not be found" when I add the using statement for the Class Library

Comment: If you've just copied and pasted your class into the new class library then the namespace for it would not have changed. Go to your class in your new class library and rename the namespace to the same as the class library name.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a reference to the class library you moved it to.
2. If the method is public (and not static) you'll need to instantiate the class :

   ```
   YourClass yourClass = new YourClass();
   yourClass.YourMethod();
   ```

If the method is public and static then you can call it directly :

```
YourClass.YourMethod();
```

and make sure not to forget the using statement, preffered to place at the top of your file:

```
using MyClassNamespace;
```